# Use available space for textbox within the parent container

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container, the width can be  50%, 60% etc.
Inside the container, there are 3 elements.

1. Label - should utilize the 100% width, must be the first row.
2. Textbox - Use available space within the parent container, here width also can vary like 50%, 60% etc.
3. Button followed by textbox, the width should be 50px.

I want to achieve the below scenario's. In the below scenario's, the button must be next to the textbox.

1. Parent container width can be vary based on that, the textbox should utilize the available space.
2. Textbox width can be vary, so the button should be on next to the textbox.

[image]

Please see the attachment for more clarity.
Kindly help me fix this scenario's with only css and html, no js.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide your html/css ?

Comment: Hi Alek, here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shahuls_md/gx8p5ch2/

Comment: There are a dozen of ways to achieve that; What are the limitations?

Comment: Case #1:According to the parent container width, the textbox should utilize the rest of space , the sibling button taking 30px width. 
Case #2:And textbox width also vary, so the button should stick next to the textbox but not float right.

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gx8p5ch2/2/)

You can give `position:absolute` to your button. SO, it will stick to the right side of the parent container.

CSS Will be:

```
.parent {
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.parent label {
    display: block;
}
.parent [type="button"] {
    position:absolute;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
}
.parent [type="text"] {
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    padding:6px 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The button should be next to the textbox(not some thing like float right). If I change the textbox size, then the button is should be next to the  textbox (like float left).